# How to change resend OTP time in Phone Number Authentication by FirebaseUI

Tags: android, authentication, firebase, firebaseui

I am using FirebaseUI to create a phone number authentication activity in my app. By default, the time for resending the OPT is 15 seconds. I want to change this time limit. How to do so?

```
public class PhoneNumberAuthentication extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 123;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        if (auth.getCurrentUser() != null) {
            // already signed in
            startActivity(new Intent(PhoneNumberAuthentication.this, MainActivity.class));
            finish();
        } else {
            // not signed in
            startActivityForResult(
                    AuthUI.getInstance()
                            .createSignInIntentBuilder()
                            .setAvailableProviders(
                                    Arrays.asList(
                                            new AuthUI.IdpConfig.Builder(AuthUI.PHONE_VERIFICATION_PROVIDER).build()
                                            ))
                            .build(),
                    RC_SIGN_IN);
        }
    }
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        // RC_SIGN_IN is the request code you passed into startActivityForResult(...) when starting the sign in flow.
        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            IdpResponse response = IdpResponse.fromResultIntent(data);
            // Successfully signed in
            if (resultCode == ResultCodes.OK) {
                startActivity(new Intent(PhoneNumberAuthentication.this,MainActivity.class));
                finish();
                return;
            } else {
                // Sign in failed
                if (response == null) {
                    // User pressed back button
                    Log.e("Login","Login canceled by User");
                    return;
                }
                if (response.getErrorCode() == ErrorCodes.NO_NETWORK) {
                    Log.e("Login","No Internet Connection");
                    return;
                }
                if (response.getErrorCode() == ErrorCodes.UNKNOWN_ERROR) {
                    Log.e("Login","Unknown Error");
                    return;
                }
            }
            Log.e("Login","Unknown sign in response");
        }
    }
}
```

I have attached the screenshot of the OPT Verification Activity:[OTP Verification Activity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/02ff3.jpg). The resend code timer counts down from 15 and when it reaches 0, it enables a resend OTP Button. I need to increase this countdown time.

Comment: got any answer for this. the one provided down is not working.

Answer (score -1):

if you only want to enable or disable resend OTP button as according to time you can use a handler as

```
        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                otpButton.setEnable(true);
            }
        }, 60000);
```

this give you a 60 second time

Comment: Thanks.. But where in my code should I put this block?

Comment: when firebasebse phoneauth otp code send and you go to otp fetch activity then in onStart method

Comment: @UttamMeerwal I know this is late, the OP and any developers who are using FirebaseUI Auth library is expecting a method in the builder class that can change the default resend SMS duration which is at the time of this writing is none.